# Optimising Dask computations (memory implications and communication overhead)

Tags: python, dask, distributed-computing, dask-distributed

I am working on a project which was initially optimised for the Python multiprocessing library, and I am trying to use Dask to distribute the work over multiple nodes. Particularly I am trying to use the SSHCluster.

In order to optimise as much as possible, I have changed the worker methods to be more fine-grained, i.e. working on the smallest level possible, requiring smaller inputs and returning smaller outputs. I am trying to utilise the least amount of memory, while taking the least amount of time to complete a single task.

The kind of data structures I have are as follows: a large dict, with inner integer values, arrays and dicts. As well as simpler dicts, arrays and sets. These are dynamic in nature, i.e. they should be changed by the worker methods and returned back to the client, and then be used by subsequent calls to the same (and other) worker methods.

I also have a dict of dicts, which is static, and some other objects that also feature static data. I am saving these properties as JSON files, using the client.upload_file method to upload the files to the workers, and using the client.register_worker_callbacks method to register these files on the worker side to be able to use them as "global shared" memory from the worker methods (this uses up some memory, especially because the data is duplicated in the memory space of each worker, however, it works quite well, because the data is loaded once upon creating the workers, and then is shared by any subsequent worker method (task) computation).

However, when it comes to the dynamic memory, this data (approx. 800 mb in size), needs to be passed to the workers in the most efficient way possible, before starting the computation of the worker method.

I came up with 3 potential ways to achieve this communication between the client and the workers:

> 1. Split the data structures into "partial data structures" based on what each worker method requires. For e.g. if the worker method will
>    be tackling person A, B, C, only include the corresponding data for A,
>    B, C. Then subsequently only return the data for A, B, C.
> 2. Scatter these data structures to the workers using: client.scatter(dynamic_obj, broadcast=true). Pass the scattered data
>    structures as futures to the workers (along with other small params).
>    Then on the worker side build the "partial data structures" for local
>    usage only, and return the results much like 1.
> 3. Use Dask data structures such as Dask.Bag or Dask.Array.

The first one works; I am just not sure whether my memory consumption is optimal. For e.g. the client is using around 6.3gb of memory, the scheduler around 2.8gb, and the workers around 2.3gb each. I am using the client.submit or the client.map methods, and then evaluating the resulting futures with the as_completed method. I am also releasing each future as soon as I evaluate its results. While I think the client is warranted to use 6.3gb of memory, I am not sure why the scheduler is using that much memory, when I should be releasing the results so quickly. The workers seem to have a baseline memory which is around 1.9gb, so 2.3gb seems to be acceptable as "working memory" while the tasks are ongoing.

The second option doesn't work. When trying to call:

```
client.scatter(dynamic_obj, broadcast=True)
```

on what I've described as "a large dict, with inner integer values, arrays and dicts", I get:

> distributed.comm.core.CommClosedError: in <TCP (closed) ConnectionPool.scatter local=tcp://127.0.0.1:58858 remote=tcop://127.0.1.1:35767>: Stream is closed

after around 32 minutes. Is this possibly because of the "nested dict" type of data structure? The collection is not even that large, and most inner dicts/arrays are empty at this point.

I am not sure about the 3rd option, especially because from the articles I read and videos I watched, it seems that these are more useful for distributed computations on large data sets, of which I don't have plenty. The data structures I am using (and referring to above) are what I have found to be the most convenient data representations of the results that need to be returned by the worker methods. However, I was wondering whether, when using Dask data structures, I could gain an automatic speed up with regards to the data communication overhead. It would be interesting if I can be pointed into the right direction in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't exactly an answer...

I think that when your data structures do not match the "collections" offered by dask (bad, array, dataframe), using ad-hoc client.submit is a fine thing to do.

Keep in mind, that you do not need to submit all of your work at the same time (this would be equivalent to a dask.delayed workflow which you might have seen elsewhere). You might, for example, submit a batch of 100 futures and wait for them to complete before submitting more; or since you are using as_completed anyway, submit a new task each time one completes. This pattern should help keep the memory usage of the scheduler low, as it can "forget" old work rather than queueing everything.

> The second option doesn't work.

Serialising a bunch of nested python objects can be more expensive in bytes and CPU time than you think. Actually JSON text might be more efficient in some cases because it's more limited in what it can represent. Also, that allows you to separate the IO transfer memory usage from the load-and parse rather than relying on pickle to do the right thing.

If your data is nested JSON-like, but actually has a consistent schema across each entry, you might be interested in [awkward array](https://awkward-array.org/doc/main/), which may be much more memory efficient and offer fast vectorised compute over your values, if you are doing numeric work.

Comment: thank you for always answering! that is a great idea that had not occurred to me. indeed until now I have only tried queuing everything at 1 go, and that very probably doesn't allow the memory usage to recover. I will also look into the "awkward array". with regards to the JSON text, are you suggesting converting the structure into a JSON string, passing it to the worker and deserializing it on that side? what Dask method would you suggest to pass the JSON string? scatter or something else?

Comment: Awkward arrays can read from JSON or be made from any iterable, so you can try all the options. Scatter is fine for objects or even text, or upload_file for files as you have done.

Comment: the batch approach improves the memory usage, especially in the scheduler. however, with this approach I've noticed that with 4 workers, I use up around 85% of the available memory on the VM, and the last worker is not doing much, only peaking at max 20%. The rest of the workers fluctuate between 20-80%, but rarely exceed 80%. could the imbalance be pertaining to the "1 by 1" task allocation, e.g. scheduler is always finding the first 3 workers available, so the last worker is not that necessary? I would also have to consider a way to try to use up more than 80% of the CPU

Comment: another question please, regarding the approach of sharing the data as JSON text (scatter) or JSON file (upload_file), how can I go about achieving this in such a way that each worker does not have to re-load the object from text or from file in the context of each worker method instance (task)? I am thinking something like: register_worker_callbacks that can be called during runtime (rather than upon starting the workers). Any ideas?

Comment: Dask will not reload data when it is required by subsequent tasks

Comment: if I convert my structure into a JSON string, pass it to the workers via client.scatter, and hold on to its future, Dask will not copy the data back and forth, and that is fine. but to use it in its original form in the worker method/s, I need to use json.load to load it back into an object, no? how can I do that once on the worker side, such that it can be re-used? if it's a significantly large object, the json.load would add additional overhead x my 100k+ tasks no?

Comment: Either make json.loads a task too, or scatter the parsed object rather than the ext (should be the same size). 
Maybe it's time you asked a new question, this thread is getting too long.